# Eclipse SVN client (Subclipse) sync issue

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, subversive

I have installed eclipse php (Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)) with subversive (4.0.2) plugin.

When trying team synchronizing, I've got 2 issues :

1. The arrows icons (which gives a preview of what's to push and what to pull) disappear after 1 second.

**This issue was solved by doing the following :**

> Install PDT addon v2.2.1 using "Install New Software"  Select Heliosn
>   update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios) then use
>   filter "PDT" to display only PDT, and select "PHP Development Tools
>   (PDT) SDK Feature" then install

2. When double clicking on a .php to see what has changed, it's blank. Any other files work properly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PDT (Php plugin for eclipse) was broken.

I decided to install eclipse Lunar latest release, then installed latest subversion Lunar plugin and connectors, and it all worked out.

Comment: If you install items from [http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios)  in eclipse Neon, will give conflicts of versiones. Uninstall all item and reinstall from [http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly/](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly/)

Answer (score 1):

1- I have neon 2 + PDT and the problem is gone **disabling**:

*"window/preference/general/appearance/label decorations/PHP Project Explorer Decorator"*

and close and reopen team synchronizing perspective

2- To resolve this problem *"help/install new software"* and use (nightly builds) 
[http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly/](http://1-%20I%20have%20neon%202%20+%20PDT%20and%20the%20problem%20is%20gone%20disabling:%20%20window/preference/general/appearance/label%20decorations/PHP%20Project%20Explorer%20Decorator%20%20and%20close%20and%20reopen%20team%20synchronizing%20perspective%20%202-%20To%20resolve%20this%20problem%20help/install%20new%20software%20and%20use%20(nightly%20builds)%20%20http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly/%20and%20install%20all%20items.)
and install all items,
[bug reported here.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507821)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your lead. Turns out my Php plugin(PDT) was somehow broken. I'm posting my solution right now

Comment: Yes, some item cant be installed because have conflicts. I ommited them.